# Auslander-Reiten quiver of quiver algebra kQ where Q is of extended dynkin type D4~

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

I am looking for literature about the Auslander-Reiten quiver of the quiver algebra $kQ$, where $Q$ is of extended dynkin type $\tilde{D_4}$ and $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Does somebody know where to find it?

Answer (score 2):

The book by Skowronski and Simson: "Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 2, Tubes and Concealed Algebras of Euclidean type" tread the representation theory of tame algebras in detail and in section 13 you can find a classifcation of indecomposable modules for tame KQ with a detailed example of the four subspace problem.

Comment: Thank you! Could one write down the irreducible representations of $\tilde{D_4}$ explicitly from it? I am looking for a concrete description of the modules and the Auslander-Reiten quiver.